# searched items dont be added to list box

Tags: c#, listbox, listboxitems

items searched in search function: the ALBUMS dont get added to the list box?
the other fields populate

can you please tell me how i can populate the listbox with the searched albums
albums be looked up using a linked list

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Assignment
{
public partial class frmAddArtist : Form
{
    AVLTree<Artist> avltree = new AVLTree<Artist>();
    LinkedList<Album> temp = new LinkedList<Album>();
    Artist artistinst;
    Album albuminst;
    string noofmembers, artistname;
    int artistcount;

    public frmAddArtist()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void label5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btnAddArtist_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string tempalbum, date;
        tempalbum = txtAlbumName.Text;
        date = dtpReleaseDate.Text.ToString();
        albuminst = new Album(tempalbum, date);
        temp.AddFirst(albuminst);
        lbAlbums.Items.Add(tempalbum);
    }

    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        artistname = txtArtistName.Text;
        noofmembers = txtNoOfMembers.Text;
        artistinst = new Artist(artistname, noofmembers, temp);
        avltree.InsertItem(artistinst);
        artistcount++;
        txtArtistName.Clear();
        txtNoOfMembers.Clear();
        txtAlbumName.Clear();
        lbAlbums.Items.Clear();
        temp.Clear();
    }

    private void btnNoOfArtist_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("The No. Artist: " + Convert.ToString(artistcount)); 
    }

    private void btnHeight_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int heightoftree = avltree.Height();
        string height = Convert.ToString(heightoftree);
        MessageBox.Show("The Height of the Tree: " + height);
    }

    private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Artist temp = new Artist(txtSearch.Text, " ", null);
        Artist result = avltree.Search(temp);
        if (result != null)
        {
            if (result.CompareTo(temp) == 0)
            {
                txtArtistName.Text = result.artistname;
                txtNoOfMembers.Text = result.noofmembers;
                foreach (Album p in result.Albumslist)
                {
                    lbAlbums.Items.Add(p.Albumname);
                }
            }
                else if(result.CompareTo(temp) <0)
                {
                    MessageBox .Show("No Match Found");
                } 

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the items into a LinkedList or a List.
Then set lbAlbums.ItemsSource=;

Comment: the albums are already in a linked list                                                                                                                                                                                                 public LinkedList<Album> Albumslist
        {
            get { return albumslist; }
            set { albumslist = value; }
        }

Comment: Then just set the ItemsSource of your ListBox to the List and everything will by fine ;)
You will have to override the ToString Merhod of your Album, otherwise you will just see namespace.Album.